# Facebook JSON "facial_data" "raw_data" format

Tags: json, facebook, image-processing, computer-vision, face-recognition

Context: The Facebook "Download Your Data" feature allows users to download some information in JSON (or HTML) format.

One of the JSON files that I found in my downloaded data is called "face_recognition.json" and contains a dictionary with a "raw_data" key whose value is a blob of data (887 characters) that looks like it is encoded into ASCII in some format that does not appear to be base64. I.e., I can't base64 decode it into anything that appears meaningful.

For additional context, some of the other key names in the JSON are "threshold_green", "threshold_yellow", "threshold_red", "example_count", and finally "raw_data".

EDIT per answer from 1/25/2019: Regardless of whether the data is filename-safe base64 encoded or not, I still can't make sense of the decoded "raw_data." After decoding (base64 file-name safe), it appears to just be some "binary data." If anyone has any idea what the data structure of the decoded data is, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**threshold_green**, **threshold_yellow** and **threshold_red** are
traffic-light-colors of some max/avg/min ***water marks*** for the quality
of the picture data to be comparable with other pictures.

Think about some *Levenshtein routine* as comparison method for the beginning,
but it surely will be much more complicated (possibly *quad-tree* analysis in an *neural network* ...).

The example count will be the number of relevant **face detection points**
for *face classification* (or the *comparison*) {you can search the web for
*Haar cascades* and for the *method of Kazemi*, if you want to learn deeper}.

The raw-data ist BASE64, but with a slightly different charset. They use
the **"URL and Filename safe" Base 64 Alphabet** with '-' and '_' instead
of '+' and '/' (see http://rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648.txt), if you
translate these first, you are able to decode the BASE64 data successfully.
(look into the http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php documentation
for a nice implementation of *base64url_encode()* and *base64url_decode()*)

*Fine, that's all you could do, for further work you'll miss the A.I. ;) !!*